# Saving Excel 2016 sheet as JPG

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can you save an Excel Sheet as JPG?

I have followed [instructions from Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Save-a-chart-as-a-picture-in-Excel-for-Windows-254bbf9a-1ce1-459f-914a-4902e8ca9217). However when I click on `Paste special` in Word, in the opened window there is no option `As: Picture (JPEG)`. There is only option is `Picture (Enhanced Metafile)`. After I save the picture from the Word document as a JPEG, the saved picture becomes half covered by black.

Comment: By saving an Excel Sheet, do you mean saving an image of the entire spreadsheet, or only a chart as in the link you referenced?

Comment: It is a large sheet, isn't it? I think a bitmap is not available due some size limit. So it uses vector format `(*.emf)` instead. You can try this workaround: Copy in Excel, paste in MSPaint (`WIN+R` type `mspaint` hit `OK`), copy in MSPaint and paste in Word.

Comment: EMF (Enhanced Metafile) is a vector format so it'll have highest quality. Next would be PNG. JPG is terrible for straight lines like in screenshots and should be avoided. The output JPG file size is usually higher than the screenshot in PNG

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced Metafile usually works really well between Office programs.

If you need something at JPEG (why? PNG would be much better for crisp lines) on disk, you could

- use 'Snipping Tool' in the windows start menu to get a screen shot and save wherever
- select the data in Excel, hit Ctrl-C or Copy, and then paste into Microsoft Paint, then save (preferable as PNG but JPEG is an option)

Answer (score 0):

When responding to questions in this forum, I may:

1. touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>
2. open Paint
3. touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
4. crop the image
5. SaveAs in the desired format

I will then have a `.jepg` file that I can embed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Excel sheet to JPG online. Find an online website first. To unload the Excel file and to click the corresponding button to convert. Then you can download the worksheet in JPG format.